# Setting initialValue on Form.Item wrapping a Cascader throws an "Uncaught TypeError: label.join is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, antd

So as soon as I set the initialValue on a Form.Item that wraps a Cascader component, I start getting errors on the console saying that label.join is not a function.

```
const optionsGender = [{value: 'Male', label: 'Male'},
            {value: 'Female', label: 'Female'},
            {value: 'Trans-Gender', label: 'Trans-Gender'}];


<Form.Item
    label="Gender"
    name="gender"
    initialValue="Female">
    <Cascader options={optionsGender} />
</Form.Item>
```

initialValues on Form.Item(s) wrapping Input(s) are working just fine.

```
<FormItem
    label="First Name" name="first_name"
    initialValue={profile.first_name}>
    <Input/>
</FormItem>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `optionsGender`?

Comment: @Yousaf Added it.

Comment: The problem is with the `Cascader`. It might just take `Object` as input. Try giving `initialValue` as an `Object` instead of a `String`. Like `{"value": "Female", "label": "Female"}`

Comment: Hi I looked the antd `Cascader` and it turns out it takes an array as `defaultValue`, so try `['Female']`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of the `displayRender` prop of `Cascader` component.

`displayRender` prop is a function that displays the selected option in the `Cascader` component. This function takes two parameters, label, and the selected option. Following is the default implementation of this function

```
label => label.join(' / ')
```

So when you set the initial value as a string, `label` is a string and you cannot call `.join()` function on a string.

#### Solution

There are 2 ways you can solve this problem:

1. Pass an array as the initial value

   ```
    <Form.Item label="Gender" name="gender" initialValue={["Female"]}>
      <Cascader options={optionsGender} />
    </Form.Item>
   ```
2. provide your own implementation of `displayRender` prop function

   ```
    <Form.Item label="Gender" name="gender" initialValue={"Female"}>
      <Cascader options={optionsGender} displayRender={label => label}/>
    </Form.Item>
   ```

**Demo:**

[image: Edit hungry-kalam-qgolm]